# How to embed java database server into distributed jar?

Tags: java, xml, jdbc, embedded-database

I am working on a project that uses JDBC through derby.jar, and I am trying to make it usable without the database server running inside NetBeans. I already have a running database (wich is not embedded) and a complete code. Here is my xml that i use.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="boltPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>entity.Termek</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/bolt;create=true"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="asd"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="asd"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Any suggestion for its modification? I tried using EmbeddedDriver instead of ClientDriver, but i got an exception that it cannot be found.
Edit:
I tried putting all required jar files in the classpath and they are all added to the libraries.

Comment: How do you build your project, maven, ant, maven through Netbeans, ant through Netbeans ? Are you developping a jar or a war ?The way to declare the dependencies is not exactly the same depending on that ...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting the derby jar and other required jars by derby in the classpath of the app? 
More instructions here
http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html

Can you edit your question to include stacktrace of errors you get after trying above link